# AWS S3-hosted Static Website Not Loading on Mobile Browsers

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-ec2

I recently learned how to deploy a Fullstack application using AWS EC2 and S3 for static website hosting. I'm currently running my application with ngrok for database access.

Here's a summary of my setup:

S3 works fine on both desktop and mobile devices.
EC2 appears to be working correctly on both desktop and mobile as well.
I didn't make any changes to the IAM user related to the S3 bucket. The issue I'm facing started after deploying a new version of the code using a YAML file with GitHub. It's worth noting that it's not the first time I've uploaded a new version, but this is the first update I made after creating the EC2 instance.

The problem is that mobile browsers are not fetching the static files, and I'm seeing the "ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT" error in the browser's developer tools on mobile. However, the site works smoothly on desktop.

I'm not sure where to begin debugging this issue, and I'd appreciate any guidance or suggestions. Could you help me understand what might be causing this problem and how to resolve it?

*** I will update question with any information i suggest me to add

Comment: Stale DNS cache perhaps? Try using a VPN, switching DNS, or other browsers. If this is an Android, try running `curl yourstaticfileurl -vvv` from Termux (install it from GitHub/F-Droid, not from Play Store)

Answer (score 2):

I faced the same problem. For me what worked was simple: When I was just clicking on the link my phone's browser was auto changing the HTTP protocol to HTTPS, then I manually changed back to HTTP and it worked just fine. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

I have same issue. The static website link is working on desktop, but not on mobile device. I have not hosted the site (linked to any domain)